# Background image won't cover when fixed is applied, but won't cover vertically when it is not applied

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to set this image as the background of the page, and for whatever reason it just won't work. The intention is to make the background image cover the page, without cropping vertically or horizontally.

Note: The CSS file is connected to the document.

```
HTML:
<body>
  <main>
    <h2 id="cityName">

    </h2>
    <div id="weatherIcon">
      <img id="weatherIconImg"/>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

CSS:
body {
background-image: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/production2hats.appspot.com/o/studentPortal%2Fassessment-web-app-essentials%2Fbackground.jpg?alt=media&token=d0e6837f-d037-4fee-97b6-313c8ea6aa80");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover fixed;
-moz-background-size: cover fixed;
-o-background-size: cover fixed;
background-size: cover fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you:

```css
body {
min-height: 100vh;
min-width: 100vw;
background-image: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/production2hats.appspot.com/o/studentPortal%2Fassessment-web-app-essentials%2Fbackground.jpg?alt=media&token=d0e6837f-d037-4fee-97b6-313c8ea6aa80");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h2 id="cityName">

    </h2>
    <div id="weatherIcon">
      <img id="weatherIconImg"/>
    </div>
  </main>
```

You should try `background-size: Cover;` may be an image will be cut from right or bottom but with `background-size: 100% 100%;` image can stretch. It totally depends on image size.

Answer (score 0):

please do not use this css attribute "background-repeat: no-repeat;" if you want full screen image.

Actually you can solve this issue in two ways. 
**1.use the fullimage and repeat the image if size of the screen is large
2. stretching the image to the full width.**

please look at the below code:

```css
body {
background-image: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/production2hats.appspot.com/o/studentPortal%2Fassessment-web-app-essentials%2Fbackground.jpg?alt=media&token=d0e6837f-d037-4fee-97b6-313c8ea6aa80");
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
 <h2 id="cityName"></h2>
 <div id="weatherIcon">
   <img id="weatherIconImg"/>
 </div>
```

another meathod is below here.

```css
body {
min-height: 100vh;
min-width: 100vw;
background-image: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/production2hats.appspot.com/o/studentPortal%2Fassessment-web-app-essentials%2Fbackground.jpg?alt=media&token=d0e6837f-d037-4fee-97b6-313c8ea6aa80");
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
 <h2 id="cityName"></h2>
 <div id="weatherIcon">
   <img id="weatherIconImg"/>
 </div>
```